# Can a NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M support 2560x1440 (16:9) resolution?

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, macbook-pro

I recently took the plunge after reading [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/the-ips-lcd-revolution.html) and bought the FSM-270YG, a 27" IPS monitor from Korea. The resolution is 2560X1440  and has 16:9 ratio. Here is the [listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/180899648226?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649#ht_16786wt_1100) that displays the item.

After receiving the monitor, I tried hooking it up to my 2010 MacBook Pro that has a NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M graphics card and the computer failed to detect the monitor. After messing around some more and restarting the computer with the monitor plugged in, the laptop was detecting the monitor but not waking it up or displaying anything on the screen. After communication with the buyer, he notified me that my graphics cards is not compatible. Apparently, although the card I have supports 2560 x 1600 resolution, it only supports a screen ratio of 16:10. The monitor I bought has a resolution of 2560x1440 at a 16:9 ratio. Is there any way I can make the card work with the monitor or am I out of luck?

EDIT: I am using a MiniDP to DVI adapter plus a DVI-Dual link cable to hook the monitor up to my laptop

Thanks!
Kevin

Comment: What are you using to connect the laptop to the monitor? Have you tried connecting anything else to it? You state two different resolutions for the monitor: 2560x1440 and 1560x1440.

Comment: my mistake, I updated the post. The external monitor is 2560x1440. I am connecting it to my MacBook Pro via a MiniDP to DVI adapter plus a DVI-Dual link cable

Comment: Your eBay link is dead, as well. I've submitted a correction.

Comment: Thanks, oops, didn't read the last part. I've updated the link again to show the listing.

Comment: It sounds like there are a lot of variables here, start by making sure your monitor works with another connection/making sure your laptop output concoction is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here with the monitor FSM-270YG LED (same seller). When it connects to the MacBook Pro (Early 2011 - AMD Radeon HD 6490M under Lion) the macbook immediately crashes and asks to reboot.

REASON: Apparently this monitor uses "Bypass" and is NOT compatible with the MacBook and a bunch of graphics cards Check info in:

[image]

Seems to work udern linux http://isotope11.com/blog/getting-the-fsm-270yg-led-korean-27-ips-panels-working-with-the-nvidia-driver-in-your-xorg-dot-conf

If it will ever work with the macbook ... is still an open question.

Comment: bummer.. really disappointing. thanks for the info. now I have to look in to shipping back to korea :/

Answer (score 0):

A quick look around Google shows me that many people use 2560x1440 resolution external monitors successfully with the GT 330M in their MacBook Pro computers. I wasn't able to find anyone who had problems with this.

My suspicion is that you got a dead monitor, or a bad cable or adapter. If you can, test all of the components on a different machine to see if one of them is faulty.

Comment: the MiniDP to DVI adaptar and Dual-link DVI cable work fine when hooked up to another monitor. I don't have another computer to test the monitor with..i am looking in to trying a different type of DVI cable to get an analog signal

Comment: i tried hooking the monitor up to my cable box via a HDMI to DVI cable  (HDMI out from the cable box and the DVI connection into the monitor). The monitor was awake (the screen was lit and the power right was blue  instead of the red it is when sleeping) which doesn't happen when hooked up to my laptop. The output on the screen was "scrambled", but I'm not sure the cable box is supposed to be compatible. Picture of output here: http://cl.ly/image/1X2V2V0h2q0E